I have some topics from python out of which I want to know the one which actually needs to be studied for data science roles specifically
The topics are as follows:

Collections
Itertools
Regex and parsing
Error and exceptions
Date and time


Based on my experience, all of these topics will be important at some point during your data science journey. A lot data science involves manipulating data and getting it into a usable format which can then be analyzed or modeled (ie the development features)
Ultimately, you can think of each of those topics as tools in your toolbox, you might draw on it, as you need it. Each of these topics can be studied extensively, which may not be necessary when working on a data science problem.
I would recommend working on projects and then learning these topics as they come up versus studying them in isolation

Thank you so much.
